# Robolectric HTTP test fails on NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I'm trying to test HTTP calls using the Robolectric test framework's [HTTP layer](http://robolectric.blogspot.hu/2011/01/how-to-test-http-requests.html).

My test class is already annotated with RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class). Here's a sample HTTP test case:

```
@Test
public void testHttpGet() {
    Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(200, "All your requests are belong to Robolectric");
    String response = ConnectionUtils.sendRequest();
    assertThat(response, equalTo("All your requests are belong to Robolectric"));
}
```

This test fails and the JUnit Failure Trace reports the following DefaultRequestDirector exception (originating from the sendRequest() call):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.<init>(Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;Lorg/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoutePlanner;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpProcessor;Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpRequestRetryHandler;Lorg/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler;Lorg/apache/http/client/AuthenticationHandler;Lorg/apache/http/client/AuthenticationHandler;Lorg/apache/http/client/UserTokenHandler;Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;)V
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientRequestDirector(AbstractHttpClient.java:660)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:625)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
```

Any ideas what might be causing the Apache class to throw an exception?

Using the current latest library, robolectric-1.2-20120730.165026-113-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer on the Robolectric Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robolectric/jWwWjQ23wHI/X9b_ZdDMJg0J

1. Right click the Robolectric Java test project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export.
2. Move the robolectric jar to the top of the list of libraries.
3. Find and remove `cached-robolectric-classes.jar`. If you followed Robolectric's installation instructions for Eclipse, this file will be under [your main Android project]/tmp.
4. Rerun JUnit and get back to work.